# why Strauss-hardcore model could has a gamma bigger than 1?

Tags: r, hybrid, spatstat

the spatstat book said clearly that a Strauss model is invalid with a gamma bigger than 1, that is true:

```
multiple.Strauss<-ppm(P1a4.multiple~1, Strauss(r=51),method='ho')    
#Warning message:
#Fitted model is invalid - cannot be simulated
```

as the L(r) function does has a trough first, I refit the data as a Strauss-hardcore model:

```
Mo.hybrid<-Hybrid(H=Hardcore(),S=Strauss(51))
multiple.hybrid<-ppm(P1a4.multiple~1,Mo.hybrid,method='ho')
#Hard core distance:    12.65963
#Fitted S interaction parameter gamma:   2.7466492
```

it interesting to see that the model fitted suceessfully, with a gamma>1 !
I want to know whether the gamma in Strauss-Hardcore model has same meaning with Strauss model, therefore could used as a indicator of aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the interpretation is similar and indicates some aggregation behaviour. The model with gamma>1 may be less intuitive to understand: Say the hardcore distance is r=12 and the Strauss interaction distance is R=50. Then you say that pairs of points within distance 12 of each other are heavily penalized (not permitted at all) while pairs of points separated by between 12 and 50 are encouraged (have a higher probability of occurring than at random). Pairs of points separated by more than 50 do not change the baseline probability (complete randomness).

Simulations from the StraussHardcore model often shows strange aggregation behavior, but it may be suitable for your data.

Comment: thanks Ege. your explanation is confirmed  by help file of StraussHard. if gamma for StraussHard is over 1, meanwhile gamma from Hybrid(Hardcore(), Geyer()) also is can over 1, what's the difference between them? certainly the value differed.

Comment: Difference between Strauss and Geyer is that Geyer has a saturation parameter `s` (positive integer) saying that for a given point the probability density is only effected by the first `s` neighbours -- any additional neighbours do not change the probability density. This technical solution means that gamma can be both above and below 1 for the Geyer model.

Comment: can you simulate Strauss model to find the threshold value of gamma for a random and a regular spatial points pattern? seem like 0.5 or lower? thansk in advance.

Comment: because some spatial aggregation index could have such threshold, sth like: over 1 suggest aggregation, between 0 and  1 suggest random,   less than 0 suggest regular.